# How do I mirror a directory with wget without creating parent directories?

Tags: linux, ftp, wget, mirror

I want to mirror a folder via FTP, like this:

```
wget --mirror --user=x --password=x ftp://ftp.site.com/folder/subfolder/evendeeper
```

But I do not want to create a directory structure like this:

> ftp.site.com -> folder -> subfolder -> evendeeper

I just want:

> evendeeper

And anything below it to be the resulting structure. It would also be acceptable for the contents of `evendeeper` to wind up in the current directory as long as subdirectories are created for subdirectories of `evendeeper` on the server.

I am aware of the `-np` option, according to the documentation that just keeps it from following links to parent pages (a non-issue for the binary files I'm mirroring via FTP). I am also aware of the `-nd` option, but this prevents creating any directory structure at all, even for subdirectories of `evendeeper`.

I would consider alternatives as long as they are command-line-based, readily available as Ubuntu packages and easily automated like wget.

Comment: With `lftp`: `lftp -c mirror <url>`

Answer (score 92, accepted):

For a path like: `ftp.site.com/a/b/c/d`

`-nH` would download all files to the directory `a/b/c/d` in the current directory, and `-nH --cut-dirs=3` would download all files to the directory `d` in the current directory.

Comment: Thanks, --cut-dirs was the silver bullet I was looking for.

Comment: I would change to --cut-dirs=4 if you need all files from directory d

Comment: -nH would only ignore the host directory for me. You can set --cut-dirs=100 for preventing almost all the pre directorys -- tick

Comment: It's fairly obvious with an URL like `ftp.site.com/a/b/c/d/` one only wants the content in `d/` and its subfolders. Is there an auto-cut option or something similar for wget, that autodetects the cut depth?

Comment: @con-f-use I was hoping the `--cut-dirs=100` trick suggested by @Rex (and in [Tony TCG's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23185705/266309)) would achieve this, but alas, it works like `-nd`, i.e. it flattens the entire hierarchy, including subdirectories below the one you're downloading. Looks like there's no automatic solution using wget alone...

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar requirement and the following combination seems to be the perfect choice:

In the below example, all the files in http://url/dir1/dir2 (alone) are downloaded to local directory /dest/dir

```
wget  -nd -np -P /dest/dir --recursive http://url/dir1/dir2
```

Thanks @ffledgling for the hint on "-nd"

For the above example:

```
wget -nd -np --mirror --user=x --password=x ftp://ftp.site.com/folder/subfolder/evendeeper
```

Snippets from manual:

```
   -nd
   --no-directories
       Do not create a hierarchy of directories when retrieving recursively.  With this option turned on, all files will get saved to the current directory, without clobbering (if a name shows up more than once, the
       filenames will get extensions .n).


   -np
   --no-parent
       Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving recursively.  This is a useful option, since it guarantees that only the files below a certain hierarchy will be downloaded.
```

Answer (score 10):

`-np` (no parent) option will probably do what you want, tied in with `-L 1` (I think, don't have a wget install before me), which limits the recursion to one level.

EDIT. ok. gah... maybe I should wait until I've had coffee.. There is a `--cut` or similar option, which allows you to "cut" a specified number of directories from the output path, so for `/a/b/c/d`, a cut of 2 would force wget to create `c/d` on  your local machine

Comment: You mean: `--cut-dirs=2` — Also, `-L` is `--relative`, so you probably meant `-l` or `--level=1`

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using:

```
-nH --cut-dirs=1
```

use:

```
-nH --cut-dirs=100
```

This will cut more directories and no folders will be created.

Note: 100 = the number of folders to skip creating.
You can change 100 to any number.

Comment: Why not just use -nd instead then?